# Find a path that contains specific nodes without back and forward edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal

I have a directed graph and and a set of nodes(set = [1,2,5,9,24...]). I want to find a path that contains all the set of nodes and this path dont contain back edges(cycles) and forward edges. For example for set = [1,3,4] the following path is acceptable:
[image]

but for the same set of nodes the following paths are not acceptable:
[image]

and

[image]

First of all i thought that it would be a good step to write bfs code for finding the nodes that i can visit from a specific starting node. Here is my code:

```
def bfs(G, s):
    q = queue.Queue()
    visited = []
    #Put s onto a FIFO queue
    q.put(s)
    #mark s as visited
    visited.append(s)
    #Repeat until the queue is empty
    while not q.empty():
        #remove the least recently added vertex v
        v = q.get()
        #for each unmarked vertex pointing from v:
        #add to queue and mark as visited
        for node in G.neighbors(v):
            if node not in visited:
                q.put(node)
                visited.append(node)
    print(visited)
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to modify bfs algorithm for finding the path containing specific nodes without back and forward edges? Can you write a pseudocode example?

Comment: What do you mean by "this path dont contain back edges(cycles) and forward edges"? The third example you give is even not a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)). Please formally describe your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem).  No efficient algorithm is known, and it is widely suspected that no efficient algorithm exists.  You can read the linked article for references that suggest a variety of algorithms for this problem.

Comment: I don't think it's this problem, since the vertices on a Hamiltonian path may *induce* additional edges, but the OP forbids these.  But I think the OP is overcomplicating things -- either the given set of vertices induces a cycle, in which case it's easy to find, or it doesn't (also easy to detect).

Comment: I think op does not forbid edges in general, but edges leading to other notes on the path.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, you could be right, but that's not how I read it.  As I read it, the question says "I want to find a path" not "I want to find a set of vertices and all edges induced by those vertices", and I don't see any indication that any additional induced edges are automatically added to the path.